# SharePoint Retention Policy

Tags: sharepoint-online, information-lifecycle-management

I have a need for a document library retention policy to send an alert to someone 3 months before the expired date, to remind them to start the process of renewing the document.

I do something similar with another document library, where I set a content type to kick off a 2010 workflow on the date that it expires. This one though they want a reminder 3 months before. We are in SPO, and I'm curious if Flow could handle something like this. I think it has a timeout of 30 days, but not sure if there is a way around that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It sounds like you've used information management policies with content types before, but in case you haven't you might find this (lengthy) blog post of use [link](https://sharepointmaven.com/set-retention-deletion-policies-files-folders-sharepoint/).  I've read that the Timer Job that triggers the notification emails can not be changed in SPO though - see final header of the blog post.

Comment: I was just looking over his blog post to see if it will cover what I need. Hopefully it comes up with something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send an alert to someone 3 months before the expired date, create retention policy to set a content type to kick off a 2010 workflow.

Then Create an workflow like the following:
[image]

Comment: I'll go this route, as it will be the easiest to implement. Maybe I'll adapt this to MS Flow once that program matures a bit. Thanks for the advice!